# Airy functions identities

Tags: reference-request, special-functions

Playing around with the Airy equation $$y''=t y$$
I came across determinant expressions of the form
$$\text{Ai}(x) \text{Bi}(y)-\text{Ai}(y) \text{Bi}(x), $$
as well as
$$ \text{Ai}(x) \text{Bi}'(y)-\text{Ai}'(y) \text{Bi}(x).$$

I was wondering if there exist any "Airy identities", similarly to the trigonometric case, which could help me simplify such expressions.

Thank you!

Comment: Where is $x$ coming from ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici $x,y$ are complex numbers. If making them real helps, you can take them to be real.

Comment: I better understand now. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to Claude Leibovici for the remarque to make the question more understandable.
$$-$$
A lot of identities can be derived from the equations of complex Airy functions which can be found in handbooks of special functions, for example :
$$-$$
Ai$(z)\quad$ : http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/AiryAi/19/
$$-$$
Bi$(z)\quad$ : http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/AiryBi/19/
$$-$$
Ai'$(z)\quad$ : http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/AiryAiPrime/19/
$$-$$
Bi'$(z)\quad$ : http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/AiryBiPrime/19/ $$-$$